# Evaluate a set of equations with unsigned variables and numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Give a series of equations, and find the value of each variable:

```
off = 4 + ran + 1  
loc = 1 + ori + off  
ori = 3 + 5  
ran = 2
```

The left-hand side is always a variable name composed of alphabets and the right side is composed of variables, unsigned integers, and the + operator

**My Thoughts:**
parse each line and convert it to

```
off= ran + 5  
loc = ori + off  
ori = 8  
ran =2
```

Store each of these in a Map<String,List> but for those, we know the
value we can store it in a different map like Map<String,Integer> ie. for ori and ran here so that we can use these values in other equation..
Now the problem arises as I will have to replace the value in the first hashmap and get some new variable values and then recursively keep on evaluating till a variable gets assigned a new value. Also, there could be a case where the left-hand variable is assigned some value. This could make it difficult to handle these lines of implementation

**Alternative:**
This could be represented as a set of linear equations in matrix form and then figure out the inverse of a matrix.
This seems to be a better approach.

Comment: I'd use a symbolics library. For example, Python's [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

Comment: You cannot store it in a Map if you have two or more equations where the left side is the same. Also, you didn't ask a question. You have put down some thoughts. What is the problem when you tried to implement these thoughts, if any?

Comment: Once I have converted it to form AX=B where A is a matrix and B is a column matrix. How can I solve this further? I am assuming this is a well-known problem and there should be a simple java code without using any libraries. But I am unable to find any

Comment: In the example it is possible to reorder the equations so that you solve them in sequence (ran, ori, off, loc). If that is not possible you will have to solve a matrix equation, which may have negative solutions, non-integer solutions, or no/multiple solutions. Do you want that or not?

Comment: @HansOlsson Yes Ideally one should be printing - solution/no solution/ multiple solutions

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with numpy and some parsing:

```py
import numpy as np

s = """
off = 4 + ran + 1
loc = 1 + ori + off
ori = 3 + 5
ran = 2
"""

labels = ['off', 'ran', 'loc', 'ori']
A = []
B = []

def add(label, row, amount):
  idx = labels.index(label)
  row[idx] += amount

for line in s.split('\n'):
    if not line:
        continue

    tokens = [x for x in line.split(' ')[::2] if len(x)]

    new_a = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    new_b = 0

    add(tokens[0], new_a, -1)

    for token in tokens[1:]:
      if token.isnumeric():
        new_b -= int(token)
      else:
        add(token, new_a, 1)

    A.append(new_a)
    B.append(new_b)

C = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
print(list(zip(labels, C)))
```

This prints:

```py
[('off', 7.0), ('ran', 2.0), ('loc', 16.0), ('ori', 8.0)]
```

Comment: So you are using the AX=B matrix or reducing it to row echelon form or whatever method is used inside numpy to solve this? Just wanted to be sure about your approach

Comment: @nick Exactly, I'm using numpy to solve A * C = B